# Can't find GTM/GTAG scripts in shopify store

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I want to defer gtag scripts until user interaction in a shopify store. Details of the theme [here](https://archetypethemes.co/collections/themes/products/shopify-theme-impulse). I have searched everywhere in the code, I have searched everywhere in the apps, but I can't find it anywhere, is there a default place where these are added from?

Tried finding the scripts inside the head,footer of the website, or an app that was automatically including them, but to no avail.